# Printing not working with Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I have an application deployed on Tomcat that needs to print a document. However, if I run Tomcat as a service, the print queue icon never shows up and does not print. If I run Tomcat via command line, the printing works fine. Has anybody seen this issue before?

Comment: Do you want to print on the server?

Comment: What do you mean print on the server?

Comment: I guess I need to be clear. I am trying to print to a printer.

Comment: Ha, ha. If Tomcat is hosted on a server in the cloud, I suppose you want to print on the client side. That's what I was referring.

Comment: Which operating server are you using

Comment: Please provide the "printing" code

Comment: I am using Windows 7 x64 box with Tomcat 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using windows as your operating system.
Then you need to give your service "[Interact with Desktop](http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/)" right. 
See following tutorial for [similar problem](https://bansalvarun.wordpress.com/tag/windows-service/).